# How to associate a Content Types to a Catalog Product on Sitefinity?

Tags: sitefinity

I'm trying to associate a list/array of Content Types to a Product, i.e, i have several content types and when creating a Product, on Sitefinity Ecommerce, i need to associate this Product with several content types.
So far i created a Dynamic Field Selector to select several conten types on the Product, this works fine until the moment i try to save it and a serialization error is thrown since i can't  set the Type of this field as a Guid[], like on Content Types fields, so i selected as long text. But since it's trying to convert a Guid[] to string it throws a error.

Anyone as any ideia on how to do this or a hint so i can follow up?

Comment: Forgot to mention i'm using Sitefinity 6.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i think i got this working...i basically based my solution on this sites: http://www.konstrui.nl/en/about-us/blog/daniel-plomp/2013/11/13/add-a-dynamic-content-selector-to-a-user-profile and http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/josh-morales/2013/07/09/selecting-dynamic-content-in-native-sitefinity-modules-with-custom-fields to programmatically add the field.

But for some reason it didn't add the field for the views (Edit and Insert) so i had to add them by hand. Below i will show what i did with more detail.

First i generated a Sitefinity Dynamic Items Field Control Selector through Sitefinity Thunder, see 2nd link for more information on how to do this.

On Global.asax.cs i added this code:

```
private void Bootstrapper_Initialized(object sender, Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ExecutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Register the dynamic field selector
        if (e.CommandName == "Bootstrapped")
        {
            RegisterFieldForProduct<AssetsSelectorElement>("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.sf_ec_prdct_skillsoftpack", "Assets");
        }
    }

public static void RegisterFieldForProduct<T>(string productType, string fieldName)
       where T : FieldControlDefinitionElement
    {

        // Check if the field is not already present for this content type
        var catalogManager = CatalogManager.GetManager();
        var itemClrType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType(productType);

        // Specify the persistent filed CLR type (e.g. String, Guid[], ContentLink).
        // Please ensure your custom field has been properly implemented to work with that CLR type
        var persistentFieldType = typeof(Guid[]);
        var itemType = itemClrType.FullName;

        // Check to see if the field exists
        var fieldExists = GetMetaFieldsForType(itemType).SingleOrDefault(f => f.FieldName == fieldName) != null;
        if (fieldExists) return;

        // Add the metafield that will hold the data
        App.WorkWith()
            .DynamicData()
            .Type(itemClrType)
            .Field()
            .TryCreateNew(fieldName, persistentFieldType)
            .SaveChanges(true);

        // Get correct module configuration depending on item type
        var manager = ConfigManager.GetManager();

        // Suppress the security
        var suppressSecurityChecks = manager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks;
        manager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;

        // Get Backend views(e.g. Edit, Create) configuration from ProductsBackendDefinitionName
        var section = Config.Get<ContentViewConfig>();
        const string definitionName = "ProductsBackendDefinitionName";
        var backendSection = section.ContentViewControls[definitionName];
        var views = backendSection.ViewsConfig.Values.Where(v => v.ViewType == typeof(DetailFormView));

        foreach (DetailFormViewElement view in views)
        {
            if (view.ViewName.Contains("sf_ec_prdct_skillsoftpack") == true)
            {
                // If there are no custom fields added before, the new field will be placed in the CustomFieldsSection
                var sectionToInsert =  CustomFieldsContext.GetSection(view, CustomFieldsContext.customFieldsSectionName, itemType);
                var fieldConfigElementType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType(typeof(T).FullName);

                // Create a new instance of our field configuration in the current view configuration
                var newElement = Activator.CreateInstance(fieldConfigElementType, new object[] { sectionToInsert.Fields }) as T;

                // Populate custom field values
                if (newElement == null) continue;

                newElement.DataFieldName = fieldName;
                newElement.FieldName = fieldName;
                newElement.Title = fieldName;
                newElement.DisplayMode = FieldDisplayMode.Write;

                sectionToInsert.Fields.Add(newElement);
                manager.SaveSection(section);
            }
        }

        // Save and restart the application
        catalogManager.SaveChanges();
        manager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = suppressSecurityChecks;
        SystemManager.RestartApplication(true);
    }
```

On Sitefinity BackEnd i had to add the field view by hand, Administration->Settings->Advanced->Catalog->Controls->ProductsBackendDefinitonName->Views->{insert_view}->Sections->Main Section->Fields

Here i selected create new, choose AssetsDefinitionName (my Content Type Definition Name), then i only added information to this fields:

- DataFieldName -> Assets (My field name)
- Write-> Write
- Field Name -> Assets (My field name)
- Field Type -> SitefinityWebApp.Fields.Assets.AssetsSelector, SitefinityWebApp (My Dynamic Items Field Control Selector)

Then i repeated the same to the other view (edit_view).

After this i could associate a list of content type to a specific product.
I think it was pretty much this, hope i didn't forgot any step.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't specify custom Guid[] fields on the built in Sitefinity content modules to use the selectors, however the folks at Falafel have a blog post that shows how to add the selectors through code: http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/josh-morales/2013/07/09/selecting-dynamic-content-in-native-sitefinity-modules-with-custom-fields

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ben, i've already found that blog and another one similar: http://www.konstrui.nl/en/about-us/blog/daniel-plomp/2013/11/13/add-a-dynamic-content-selector-to-a-user-profile. The guys at Telerik answered me that Sitefinity 7 should come out with this functionality out of the box. We will see...for now i'm still trying to figure this out...

Comment: I just got this from Sitefinity: "The Sitefinity 7.0 release is expected during the second half of next week, between 9th and 11th of April" and the release notes list, "Manage Any Content Relationship" here's a video showing it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hef5tJEFNvE

Not sure what your time frame is but it might be worth it to wait then upgrade.